# Apache cordova warning on

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I added this line to my config.xml file

```
....
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" 
             target="/manifest/application" 
             mode="merge">
    <application android:allowBackup="false"/>
</edit-config>
```

but when i run "cordova platform add android" i obtain the following message "Conflict found, edit-config changes from config.xml will overwrite plugin.xml changes"

Is any problem? 
Whose is the correct way to add this properties to my android-manifest file without obtain this message?

I need to prevent than android make backups of my localstorage values

I use cordova 6.4.0
Thanks in advante

Comment: have you got solution?